# I Can Not Upload My Files Into Ubuntu One

Tags: ubuntu-one

when i upload a file in ubuntu one it just show me this:

[image]

and wait on this for hours

whats the problem?

Comment: Please edit your question to provide more details. What version of Ubuntu are you using, for instance? Are you logged in when you open the Ubuntu One control panel? Does it give any useful information?

Comment: i`m in windows :)

Comment: yes i` logged in

Comment: You don't think it's worth saying that you're using Windows when you ask questions on a Ubuntu support site? You should say which version of Windows you're using too.

Comment: this service is about ubuntu :) 
i`m using windows 7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was a bug with the site, where this would happen, previously. I think it is fixed now. If it still happens, this belongs in a bug report, not a question on here. Also, we have a client port to Windows now, so the web site isn't entirely necessary to use there. :)